# Javascript function copies

Tags: javascript, function

I have a question about how javascript stores functions internally.
Given this code:

```
var makesomething = function (x) {
    var thing = {
        x: x 
    };

    thing.do = function () {
        this.x++;
    };

    return thing;
};

var x1 = makesomething(1);
var x2 = makesomething(2);
```

Since I called the makesomething function twice, does that mean that there are essentially two copies of the "do" function or do the objects have reference to the same function but get called with different closure?

Comment: use jsfiddle.net for demo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two copies, one created each time you called `makesomething()`.

You'll notice that `x1.do === x2.do` is `false`.

If instead you do this:

```
var doIt = function() {
    this.x++;
};
var makesomething = function (x) {
    var thing = {
        x: x 
    };

    thing.do = doIt;

    return thing;
};

var x1 = makesomething(1);
var x2 = makesomething(2);
```

Then both refer to the same function, and `x1.do === x2.do` will be `true`.

Comment: There are conceptually two copies of the "do" function, but it may well be the case that the runtime only keeps one copy of the actual "compiled" code.

Comment: @go-oleg - `thing` is "just" the way that access to `do()` is made available outside of `makesomething()`, it's not an essential part of the concept - `makesomething()` could just return `do()` directly without there being a `thing` and still there would be two copies of `do()`.

Comment: @Pointy - Good point, although that's obviously going to depend on the particular JS implementation. In my not-very-humble opinion the conceptual copies are what matter here, since you can code similar things that'll have only one conceptual or actual copy...

Comment: @nnnnnn yes I agree - I mention that only to assuage the fears of those who worry that a big local function takes up a lot of space because the code is replicated for each instance. In modern JavaScript VMs, I really doubt that happens (except perhaps in exotic circumstances).